# google app engine runs old node js version

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

i'm trying to deploy a nodejs app to google cloud, using the app engine.
after running 'npm start' script i get an error because the node js version running is 6.11.1, thus incompatible with my code (developed on local machine running v8.4)

this is the error:

`npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! WageCalcs@1.0.0 start: node server.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1`

i've tried setting the node js version using the "engines" property, and also removing it (the documentation says node version should be set to latest by default), and still getting the same error.
also tried updating the node version using nvm, but it seems i'm not authorized to do so.

any ideas?

Comment: well i've managed to install the new node version, still unable to make it run (trien nvm use and so on)

Answer (score 0):

think i've found the solution:

1. install newest version of node js using `sudo nvm install stable`
2. run remove "engines" property from `package.json`